# How to implement KeyStoreSpi.store(KeyStore.LoadStoreParameter param)?

Tags: java, cryptography, keystore, jce, jca

I'm implementing a Java key store  and one of the methods I could override is [`KeyStoreSpi.engineStore(KeyStore.LoadStoreParameter param)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStoreSpi.html#engineStore%28java.security.KeyStore.LoadStoreParameter%29), which is supposed to store the key store based on the supplied parameters.

I don't understand how to implement this method, for two reasons:

1. Apparently `param` can be null. In this case, how does my class know where to store the data?
2. Supposing `param` is not null - it still doesn't provide any output location information. The `LoadStoreParameter` argument is a loose wrapper around [`ProtectionParameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.ProtectionParameter.html), which seems to only provide access to password information. Again, nothing about where to store this keystore.

Any suggestions on how to tackle implementing this? I'm leaning towards not overriding this  method and relying on the default implementation, which throws `UnsupportedOperationException`. But that's simply avoiding the problem.

I've tried Googling for "*extends KeyStoreSpi*" for examples of key store source files, but nobody seems to implement this method. I guess there might be a reason for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `KeyStore.engineStore(KeyStore.LoadStoreParameter)` and `KeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(KeyStore.LoadStoreParameter)` are really needed only when the keystore format is not based on a single file, for example the keystore itself is a directory and entries are individual files inside that directory.

When the keystore format is a single file then stream-based versions of `engineStore`/`engineLoad` usually suffice and there is no need to overwrite param-based versions.

Assuming that the keystore is indeed can not be represented as a single file and therefore the keystore can not be loaded or saved using stream-based API:

1. Throw `UnsupportedOperationException` from `KeyStore.engineStore(OutputStream,char[])` and `KeyStore.engineStore(InputStream,char[])` methods.
2. Create `class MyLoadStoreParameter implements KeyStore.LoadStoreParameter` that will contain all the information required to store or load a keystore, like the path to the directory for the example above, password, etc. Making it immutable is an obviously good thing. Your keystore implementation can even define multiple variants of `LoadStoreParameter` of the keystore has multiple external representations.
3. Implement `KeyStore.engineStore(KeyStore.LoadStoreParameter)` and `KeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(KeyStore.LoadStoreParameter)` accordingly.

You should throw `IllegalArgumentException` when `KeyStore.LoadStoreParameter` argument is not an instance of `MyLoadStoreParameter`. That will automatically cover the case when the parameter is `null`.

After checking the param type and casting it you just proceed to write or read the keystore in your specific external representation using the information contained in the param.

Comment: But of course... I was stupidly forgetting that I could provide an implementation of `LoadStoreParameter` if I so wished. Great answer. I'll stick with your original suggestion - since my key store is file-based, I'll not override the param-based versions.